# Testing an async function with Jasmine in Meteor

Tags: javascript, testing, meteor, jasmine, integration

I have looked at several other questions related to this on Stackoverflow, but I still can't seem to solve my problem.  No matter what I seem to do, it seems that either Meteor.call doesn't get invoked, or if I can get it to be invoked (such as in the code sample below), no matter what the `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL` is set to, I continue to get the following error:

`Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

This is what my Jasmine test looks like:

```
it("Should be created and not assigned to anyone", function(done) {
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 5000000;

    // Confirm that the User Has Logged in
    expect(Meteor.userId()).not.toBeNull();

    var contact = null;
    var text = "This is a testing task";
    spyOn(Tasks, "insert");
    spyOn(Meteor, "call");

    Meteor.call('addTask', contact, text, function(error, result) {
      expect(error).toBeUndefined();
      expect(result).not.toBeNull();
      done();
    });

    expect(Meteor.call).toHaveBeenCalled();

  });

});
```

And my addTask function looks like this:

```
Meteor.methods({

  addTask: function (contact, text) {
     ... // addTask Code, removed for brevity
  },
});
```

Iv been stuck on this for weeks, any help anyone can provide would be super helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expectations inside the hander are never executed, because Jasmine does not invoke the original .call() method. To make it work, instead of `spyOn(Meteor, "call");` you should write `spyOn(Meteor, "call").and.callThrough();` which will call the original handler after executing Jasmine spying logic.

Comment: Wow.  That worked perfectly.  The function is now throwing an error, but at least the expectations inside the handler are FINALLY BEING CALLED!  Thank you good sir!

Comment: Could you explain to me why we would ever use just `spyOn(Meteor, "call") `and not want to callThrough?

Comment: Sometimes (actually, most of the times, I guess), people want to check just if some method was called, or check how many times it was called, they test the method itself with different tests.

Comment: @MaximGritsenko How would I do this without a callThrough to the actual implementation? Can I stub the return value of the actual implementation and just pass that stubbed value into the callback function?

Comment: @Joe, I'm not sure what your qeustion is. If you spy on a method and need it to be actually executed you add .and.callThrought(). If you just need to check if the method was called without executing it, you leave just spy.