# Meteor.call() with Jasmine doesn't work properly

Tags: meteor, callback, jasmine

I have a problem with Meteor.methods. I need to test quite complicated function but i don't know how get the return value. For my own needs I wrote a trivial code:

```js
Meteor.methods({
  returnTrue: function() {
    return true;
    },
    returnFalse: function(){
     return false;
    }
   });
```

Then i wrote also trivial test in Jasmine:

```js
describe("Function", function() {
  var tmp;
  it("expect to be true", function(){
    Meteor.call('returnTrue', function(error, result){
  if(error){
           tmp = false;
  }
  else{
    tmp = result;
     }
  });
    expect(tmp).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

And in my test i have  Expected undefined to be true.
I was trying to go through it using Session.set and Session.get but with the same result.
Any idea how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31714532/testing-an-async-function-with-jasmine-in-meteor) is a question that might peak your interest. A few things are misguided in your code:

- Your call does not reach the actual server method
- Your `expect` is called outside of the method's callback, hence `tmp` is not set yet!

Here is a suggestion!

```
describe("Function", function() {
  var tmp;
  it("expect to be true", function(){
    spyOn(Meteor, "call").and.callThrough(); // to actually call the method
    Meteor.call('returnTrue', function(error, result){
     if(error){
           tmp = false;
     }
     else{
       tmp = result;
     }
     expect(tmp).toBe(true); // moved the check inside the callback, once the call is actually executed
     });
    expect(Meteor.call).toHaveBeenCalled(); // check if the method has been called
  });
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you very much, it works perfect!